# Is it possible to create an ArcGIS library?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, design, dll

Can I create my own ArcGIS library that contains commonly used features inside my own functions/methods? I would like to make a dll that can be reference in my projects for using common features such as Geo-Coding addresses or creating a `FieldsCollection` or an `ITable`. Will this be a problem due to licensing and having to verify it?

Comment: That's not really the way DLLs work.  You couldn't possibly extract *just* the functions you need any bury them in your own DLL (and if you could it certainly would be a license violation)..

Comment: What I meant was creating my own functions. For example, a function that takes in a few parameters and geocodes addresses from a table. I could see this process being used in multiple programs I have and it would be nice to just be able to reference a dll and call the proper function.

Comment: You could certainly create libraries that do the same things, but they would not be object-compatible (you can't make your own `ITable` interface which would be accepted by Esri methods).  But if you're talking about a helper library of common-used functions to be used ***in addition to*** the Esri libraries, then that's just best practice.

Comment: @Vince that is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: You could call a script tool or model from a script tool or model builder, it wouldn't be compiled but would be a *library* of common tasks. Would that be what you're after? Note: Feature is a keyword, I wouldn't use it in a question unless you're talking about IFeature objects, a better word would be 'task' or 'process', just to avoid misconception.

Comment: To compliment @MichaelMiles-Stimson comment if you were thinking of creating custom geo-processing tools using ArcObjects then you would want to be looking at what are called GPFunction tools, help about these are available [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Custom_geoprocessing_function_tools/000100000mrs000000/). You could build a library of these and as they are geo-processing tools they can be used in model builder to combine into complex workflows.

Comment: Library construction techniques with C# is really a software engineering issue, "off the reservation" of GIS SE topics.